# How to install/use sshuttle on Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, vpn

How exactly can I install/use [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) under Fedora? It's not in the repositories

Comment: Lance on the page *you* linked to there is a giant headline about half way down the page that says **"This is how you use it:"** that covers both downloading and usage. Please spend time using already written project documentation FIRST, then ask questions here later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just get it from github either through git

```
$ git clone git://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle.git
```

or simply download a recent package and unpack it

```
$ wget https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/tarball/master
$ tar xvzf <filename>
```

And then simply enter the directory and run it. You can move it to /opt/ or anywhere else, where you need it, then hack some simple init scripts or whatever you require.

There is also a [SRPM prepared for SUSE](http://ftp.suse.de/repositories/security/SLE_11/src/sshuttle-0.20110503-1.1.src.rpm) and with a bit of hacking probably you can rebuild it on fedora if you feel safer with RPM package.